Python - Priority-Based Conditional Data Transformation
I have a use case of a form with 3 dropdowns ( A, B and C for this example). They each have 4 options:

Which gives me data per record/ID like this:
data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'A_OLD': ['A1', 'A4', 'A3', 'A4'],
    'A_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Priority_A_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'B_OLD': ['B2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2'],
    'B_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Priority_B_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'C_OLD': ['C4', 'C3', 'C1', 'C2'],
    'C_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Priority_C_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


I want to change the naming of the options. I need to change all the old data to the new values. The complexity comes in due to the following:

Some of the values will not only change the value of 1 dropdown value, but also desides the change in another dropdown
This might lead to conflicts between 2 (or more) new values.
To resolve most of the conflicts I added priotities


If I apply the conversion, taking into account the priorities, I want my result to be like this:
ID   A_OLD  B_OLD  C_OLD  A_NEW    B_NEW       C_NEW
1    A1     B2     C4     A-1      B-2         C-4
2    A4     B1     C3     A-1<     B-1         C-3
3    A3     B1     C1     A-3<     B-1         C-1
4    A4     B2     C2     A-4      B-1, B-2<   C-2

The '<' gives an indication of which values were affected by the cross-over and priorities.
Or in the table with priorities it looks like this:

To make it more clear I also created an extra image:


I know that this is possible, with the loop, if/else and the comparison of the priorities it should do it, but I can't get to the right answer.
I gor pretty far, though the solution is not pretty (quiet extensive for loop..), and the comparison between priorities is something I'm stuck at at the moment as I get this solution from the code I have:

My code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'A_OLD': ['A1', 'A4', 'A3', 'A4'],
    'A_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Priority_A_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'B_OLD': ['B2', 'B1', 'B1', 'B2'],
    'B_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Priority_B_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'C_OLD': ['C4', 'C3', 'C1', 'C2'],
    'C_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    'Priority_C_NEW': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
}

conversionTable_data = {
    'Dropdown': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
    'Value_OLD': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4'],
    'Value_NEW': ['A-1', 'A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4', 'B-1', 'B-2', 'B-3', 'B-4', 'C-1', 'C-2', 'C-3', 'C-4'],
    'Priority_NEW': [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2],
    'Other_Dropdown_Change': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'A', np.nan, np.nan, 'A', 'A', 'B', np.nan, np.nan],
    'Change_Value_Other_Dropdown': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'A-1a', np.nan, np.nan, 'A-2a', 'A-3a', 'B-1a',
                                    np.nan, np.nan],
    'Priority_Other_Dropdown': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 1, 1, np.nan, np.nan]
}

# Convert string holding columns to 'object' type
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['A_NEW'] = df['A_NEW'].astype('object')
df['B_NEW'] = df['B_NEW'].astype('object')
df['C_NEW'] = df['C_NEW'].astype('object')

df_conversionTable = pd.DataFrame(conversionTable_data)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # For A A
    OldRowA = row['A_OLD']
    filtered_conversionTable_A = df_conversionTable[(df_conversionTable['Dropdown'] == 'A') & (df_conversionTable['Value_OLD'] == OldRowA)]

    if not filtered_conversionTable_A.empty:
        df.at[index, 'A_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_A['Value_NEW'].iloc[0]
        df.at[index, 'Priority_A_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_A['Priority_NEW'].iloc[0]

        # Check for Other_Dropdown_Change
        if pd.notna(filtered_conversionTable_A['Other_Dropdown_Change'].iloc[0]):
            DropdownType = filtered_conversionTable_A['Other_Dropdown_Change'].iloc[0]
            if DropdownType == 'B':
                NEW = 'B_NEW'
                PRIORITY = 'Priority_B_NEW'
                OLD = 'B_OLD'
            elif DropdownType == 'C':
                NEW = 'C_NEW'
                PRIORITY = 'Priority_C_NEW'
                OLD = 'C_OLD'
            else:
                print("Mistake in Type")
                continue  # Skip to next iteration

            # Check if NEW column is not NaN
            if pd.notna(row[NEW]):
                # Compare priority
                if pd.notna(row[PRIORITY]) and row[PRIORITY] < filtered_conversionTable_A['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                    df.at[index, NEW] = filtered_conversionTable_A['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                    df.at[index, PRIORITY] = filtered_conversionTable_A['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                elif row[PRIORITY] == filtered_conversionTable_A['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                    # Concatenate values
                    combi_new_value = row[NEW] + '_' + row[OLD]
                    df.at[index, NEW] = combi_new_value
            else:
                # If NEW is NaN, update it
                df.at[index, NEW] = filtered_conversionTable_A['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                df.at[index, PRIORITY] = filtered_conversionTable_A['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]

    # For B

    OldRowB = row['B_OLD']
    filtered_conversionTable_B = df_conversionTable[(df_conversionTable['Dropdown'] == 'B') & (df_conversionTable['Value_OLD'] == OldRowB)]

    if not filtered_conversionTable_B.empty:
        if pd.notna(row['B_NEW']):
            # Compare priority
            if pd.notna(row['Priority_B_NEW']) and row['Priority_B_NEW'] < \
                    filtered_conversionTable_B['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                df.at[index, 'B_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_B['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                df.at[index, 'Priority_B_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_B['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
            elif row['Priority_B_NEW'] == filtered_conversionTable_B['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                # Concatenate values
                combi_new_value = row['B_NEW'] + '_' + filtered_conversionTable_B['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                df.at[index, 'B_NEW'] = combi_new_value
        else:
            df.at[index, 'B_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_B['Value_NEW'].iloc[0]
            df.at[index, 'Priority_B_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_B['Priority_NEW'].iloc[0]

        # Check for Other_Dropdown_Change
        if pd.notna(filtered_conversionTable_B['Other_Dropdown_Change'].iloc[0]):
            DropdownType = filtered_conversionTable_B['Other_Dropdown_Change'].iloc[0]
            if DropdownType == 'A':
                NEW = 'A_NEW'
                PRIORITY = 'Priority_A_NEW'
                OLD = 'A_OLD'
            elif DropdownType == 'C':
                NEW = 'C_NEW'
                PRIORITY = 'Priority_C_NEW'
                OLD = 'C_OLD'
            else:
                continue  # Skip to next iteration

            # Check if NEW column is not NaN
            if pd.notna(row[NEW]):
                # Compare priority
                if pd.notna(row[PRIORITY]) and row[PRIORITY] < filtered_conversionTable_B['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                    df.at[index, NEW] = filtered_conversionTable_B['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                    df.at[index, PRIORITY] = filtered_conversionTable_B['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                elif row[PRIORITY] == filtered_conversionTable_B['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                    # Concatenate values
                    combi_new_value = row[NEW] + '_' + filtered_conversionTable_B['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                    print(combi_new_value)
                    df.at[index, NEW] = combi_new_value
            else:
                # If NEW is NaN, update it
                df.at[index, NEW] = filtered_conversionTable_B['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                df.at[index, PRIORITY] = filtered_conversionTable_B['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]

    # For C
    OldRowC = row['C_OLD']
    filtered_conversionTable_C = df_conversionTable[(df_conversionTable['Dropdown'] == 'C') & (df_conversionTable['Value_OLD'] == OldRowC)]

    if not filtered_conversionTable_C.empty:
        if pd.notna(row['C_NEW']):
            # Compare priority
            if pd.notna(row['Priority_C_NEW']) and row['Priority_C_NEW'] < \
                    filtered_conversionTable_C['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                df.at[index, 'C_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_C['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                df.at[index, 'Priority_C_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_C['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
            elif row['Priority_C_NEW'] == filtered_conversionTable_C['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                # Concatenate values
                combi_new_value = row['C_NEW'] + '_' + filtered_conversionTable_C['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                df.at[index, 'C_NEW'] = combi_new_value
                print("geplakte versie C:")
                print(combi_new_value)
        else:
            df.at[index, 'C_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_C['Value_NEW'].iloc[0]
            df.at[index, 'Priority_C_NEW'] = filtered_conversionTable_C['Priority_NEW'].iloc[0]

        # Check for Other_Dropdown_Change
        if pd.notna(filtered_conversionTable_C['Other_Dropdown_Change'].iloc[0]):
            print("test")
            DropdownType = filtered_conversionTable_C['Other_Dropdown_Change'].iloc[0]
            if DropdownType == 'A':
                NEW = 'A_NEW'
                PRIORITY = 'Priority_A_NEW'
                OLD = 'A_OLD'
            elif DropdownType == 'B':
                NEW = 'B_NEW'
                PRIORITY = 'Priority_B_NEW'
                OLD = 'B_OLD'
            else:
                print("Error in Type")
                continue  # Skip to next iteration

            # Check if NEW column is not NaN
            if pd.notna(row[NEW]):
                # Compare priority
                if pd.notna(row[PRIORITY]) and row[PRIORITY] < filtered_conversionTable_C['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                    df.at[index, NEW] = filtered_conversionTable_C['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                    df.at[index, PRIORITY] = filtered_conversionTable_C['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                elif row[PRIORITY] == filtered_conversionTable_C['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]:
                    # Concatenate values
                    combi_new_value = row[NEW] + '_' + filtered_conversionTable_C['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                    df.at[index, NEW] = combi_new_value
            else:
                # If NEW is NaN, update it
                df.at[index, NEW] = filtered_conversionTable_C['Change_Value_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]
                df.at[index, PRIORITY] = filtered_conversionTable_C['Priority_Other_Dropdown'].iloc[0]

Additional Comment after edit
My code at the moment (apart from not being very pretty) seems to be able to find the correct new value for the dropdowns but it does not do the extra replacement of 'Other dropdown change' yet. Though I have not checked everything, it seems like this is the only problem left..

but I can't get to the right answer. -  pls post what you have tried...That would be helpful to assist the next steps

@Bhargav little late, but I added my code, hopefully it still understandable of the result I would like to have (and the logic behind it)
